# An intuitive way of understanding how logistic regression predicts on unseen combinations of variables

Tags: machine-learning, logistic

I'm looking for an intuitive way of explaining how logistic regression predicts on unseen combinations of variables. Consider for example I build a logistic regression model which looks at:

**Coefficients:**

- Gender (male and female)
- Age Brackets (under 30 / 30 or over)
- Favourite Soda (coca-cola, lemonade, fanta)

**Outcome of interest:**

- Will buy a burger (1/0)

The summary() for this model will then provide me with logits for each coefficient, e.g.

*These are purely hypothetical*

**Model Output:**

- Intercept: 1.1
- Gender Male: 0.72
- Age: Over 30 (-0.05)
- Soda: Lemonade(-0.04)
- Soda: Fanta (0.21)

Within the original dataset, I might not have a combination of the following:
*Female under 30 whose favourite soda is lemonade*

However, the model will allow me to build a prediction for the propensity of buying a burger based on these variable values. How can I explain intuitively how the model is able to make these predictions, based on the lack of cases which fit this combination in the data?

Comment: Note that this question isn't specific to logistic regression. The same thing could arise for any linear regression model. Recall that the difference between ordinary linear regression and logistic regression is that the latter model has a binary output variable ($y$), whereas the former has a continuous output. I.e. for logitistic regression $y \in \{0, 1\}$, and for plain linear regression, $y \in \mathbb{R}$. For either model the *input* variables $x_i$ may be either continuous or binary (or categorical, encoded using binary variables.)

Comment: Very true. I suspect then I am interested in resources which will help explain in layman terms how regression works in this respect.